# Unable to access jarfile ./lib/proguardgui.jar

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to retrace a stack trace I received on the Android Market. I used proguard with the APK before submitting the app to the market. Unfortunately every time I run the retrace tool I get the "Unable to access jarfile ./lib/proguardgui.jar" error.

I am running on a Mac OS X Lion.

```
Manuel-Ciosicis-MacBook-Pro:bin manuelciosici$ pwd
/Applications/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/proguard/bin
Manuel-Ciosicis-MacBook-Pro:bin manuelciosici$ sudo ./retrace.sh -verbose /Users/manuelciosici/Documents/workspace/TweakkerAllOperatorsApn/proguard/mapping.txt /Users/manuelciosici/Desktop/obfuscated_trace.txt 
Password:
Unable to access jarfile ./lib/retrace.jar
Manuel-Ciosicis-MacBook-Pro:bin manuelciosici$
```

This is the first time I'm using proguard with an app. I know for sure that the mapping.txt file is the correct one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a path problem. Try running the proguardgui.jar manually (not via your script), does that work?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It works if I run it directly. That means the Google provided scripts have some issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script is very simple, but it turns out that it fails if it's invoked as `./retrace.sh`. It does work if it's invoked as `bin/retrace.sh` from a directory higher up, or with an absolute path, for instance. This is my mistake; I'll fix this for the next release (ProGuard 4.7).